# how to use ckeditor in an angular js web App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ckeditor

I am struggling to use `ckeditor` within my html page built in `angularjs`.

I have tried so many examples.

```
ng-ckeditor directive
ckeditor directive
```

But none of those examples helped me.

I  want a textarea where I can input images within it and edit its contents style (Like in `ckeditor`).

Anyone please give me a clear example or demo fiddle on how to use `ckeditor` in `angularjs`.

I have also tried custom directive. It's not working.

Is  there any alternative for ck editor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor. Step 1-3 are actually documented quite well in the README.md and the rest is pretty easy to develop...

1. get the angular-ckeditor: git clone -depth=50
   https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor
2. download resoureces via
   bower: bower install angular-ckeditor
3. Write yourself a controller
   (see example in the README.md)
4. link your js files in your html, keep
   track of the order:

use your controller and the directive inside your html as described. If you would like to pre-initialize your editor with data from your html, you could use something like this:

```
data-ng-init="content='this is a text with &lt;a href=&quot;http://localhost/whatever.html&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;an embedded Link&lt;/a&gt;'" contenteditable="true" ready="onReady()">
```

or you init your model variable(s) in your controller (hardcoded or via $http).

I have got this from [How to use ckeditor in angular JS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429105/how-to-use-ckeditor-in-angular-js-app). and its worked for me.